# Change cell subview height after cell animation is ended Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios10, uitableview

I use `Swift 3.0` and have `tableViewCell` and its subview.
I use `heightForRowAt` function to change `cellView` height.

I have two states of `cellView`: default and expanded.
`CellViewSubview` has visible borders.

`CellView` and `cellViewSubview` are connected with `leading`, `trailing`, `top` and `bottom` constraints. When I change the height of the `cellView`, `cellViewSubview` automatically changes its height to fit. Also I need to say that `cellView` is changing with animation, I use the following to implement this:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Everything works fine except that the `cellViewSubview` height is changed instantly without animation. So it means that I see how `cellViewSubview` border 'jumps' to the top without animation.

I faced with this problem only in `IOS 10.0`. In `IOS < 10.0` animation was simultaneous. How to make the `cellView` and the `cellViewSubview` change their height simultaneously with animation?

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me:

I've stopped using `bottom equal constraint` between `cellView` and `cellViewSubview`. Instead of it I've set `height constraint` to the `cellViewSubview` and change its height after `heightForRowAt` is complete.